# Where can I ask questions related to my my career options?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any branch of Stack Exchange where I can ask questions related to my education and career?

Comment: are you talking postgraduate studies?

Comment: yes i want to do B.tech so something related to that and also hae some question related to M.tech

Comment: ther is the problem it not need to be confined to one feild

Comment: that's fine, just as long as you keep your questions within the guidelines

Answer (score 8):

For questions about postgraduate studies and career pathways, [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com) is where you could ask.  As always, be sure you read the '[About](https://academia.stackexchange.com/about)' page to make sure that your question is on-topic for the site.

Answer (score 2):

For questions related to problems you are facing in your career, [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go. However, asking, *"What job should I choose?"* or *"How do I become a...?"* are both [off-topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Take a look at [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) before asking a question, and make sure that your question also follows the [guidelines](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/) for the site before asking. If you aren't sure, you can also always ask in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) or on the [meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Not trying to discourage you from asking, just encouraging you to do the footwork first lest your question get closed and you end up discouraged anyway!